# SOLVED How to trigger animation on widget rebuild?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I will describe what my app is doing, what I am trying to achieve, and what I've tried - in this order.

I have an application, where one of the screens, let's call it `FooScreen`, contains a few widgets, but mainly it displays an image. Users can tap a button to display the following image. This functionality of changing image is handled with `Provider` - when the user taps a button, `currentAssetName` changes and notifies listeners. Because of this, the whole screen doesn't rebuild, only the widget responsible for displaying an image, let's call it `FooImage`

```dart
class FooScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
       ...Some widgets
       FooImage()
       ....
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class FooImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooImage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fooProvider = context.watch<FooProvider>();
    final assetName = fooProvider.assetName;
    return Image.asset(assetname);
  }
}
```

Currently, when the asset name changes and renders a new image, it displays a bad-looking flash on the screen. I want this image to have animation when changed.

I tried to create a wrapper widget, let's call it `FooWrapper`, where I create animation on `initState()` and pass it to `FooImage`

```dart
class FooWrapper extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<FooWrapper> createState() => _FooWrapperState();
}

class _FooWrapperState extends State<FooWrapper> 
   with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late Animation<double> animation;
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 600).animate(controller);
    controller.forward();
  }
 
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // I am aware that disposing `late` variable ain't smartest thing to do,
    //  I will change it when I will make it work 
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FooImage(animation: animation)
  }
}
```

As it can be seen, `FooImage` changed

```dart
class FooImage extends AnimatedWidget {
  const FooImage(super.key, required Animation<double> animation) : super(listenable: animation);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fooProvider = context.watch<FooProvider>();
    final assetName = fooProvider.assetName;
    final animation = listenable as Animation<double>;

    return Image.asset(
      height: animation.value,
      width: animation.value,
      assetName,
    );
  }
}
```

Right now, it works only when `FooScreen` is rendered for the first time, when I change the image it still only flashes. I tried some gymnastics to make it work, but no results.
**I'd appreciate any tips regarding how should I handle it**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work, but I am almost sure that it is not the best way to handle it.

I watch `fooProvider` in `FooWrapper` and pass it as an argument to the `FooImage`. I also changed `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` to `TickerProviderStateMixin` and moved controller and animation definitions to `didChangeDependencies()` to trigger it before every rebuild.

```dart
class FooWrapper extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<FooWrapper> createState() => _FooWrapperState();
}

class _FooWrapperState extends State<FooWrapper> 
   with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late Animation<double> animation;
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 600).animate(controller);
    controller.forward();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
 
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // I am aware that disposing `late` variable ain't smartest thing to do,
    //  I will change it when I will make it work 
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fooProvider = context.watch<FooProvider>();
    return FooImage(fooProvider, animation: animation)
  }
}
```

```dart
class FooImage extends AnimatedWidget {
  const FooImage(this.fooProvider, super.key, required Animation<double> animation) : super(listenable: animation);

  final FooProvider fooProvider;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final assetName = fooProvider.assetName;
    final animation = listenable as Animation<double>;

    return Image.asset(
      height: animation.value,
      width: animation.value,
      assetName,
    );
  }
}
```